# Replace negative values in pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I've got a series like the following:

```
s = pd.Series({'val1': 'a', 'val2': 'b', 'other_val1': 1, 'other_val2': -1, 'other_val3': 3, 'other_val4': -1.5})

val1            a
val2            b
other_val1      1
other_val2      0
other_val3      3
other_val4   -1.5
dtype: object
```

I want to replace all negative values by 0, however I could only find methods that work with dataframes.
I tried to play around with `s.mask` and `s.loc` however I had problems with the mixed types.

Expected output would be

```
val1          a
val2          b
other_val1    1
other_val2    0
other_val3    3
other_val4    0
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) + [`Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) to create a boolean mask, then use this `mask` to substitue `0` values in the series:

```
mask = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').lt(0)
s.loc[mask] = 0
```

Result:

```
val1          a
val2          b
other_val1    1
other_val2    0
other_val3    3
other_val4    0
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
series = {'val1': 'a', 'val2': 'b', 'other_val1': 1, 'other_val2': -1, 'other_val3': 3, 'other_val4': -1.5}
replaced_series = {k:0 if str(v).lstrip('-+').isdigit() and int(v)<0 else v for (k,v) in series.items()}
```